# Finding on-screen region in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2

Seems like this should be easy and obvious but I can't find the answer anywhere. I'm using `JavaFX` 2 and I need to find the width and height of the region of a node that is currently being displayed on screen to the user (NOT the width and height of the node in the whole layout).

So if the window is scrolled so that my node is halfway off the edge to the right, I'd expect to get a displayed width of half the node's width and a displayed height equal to the full height. Should be easy; isn't. Anyone know how it can be done?

A half-acceptable solution for me would be to use the dimensions of the window itself. Is this the same as the width / height of the `Stage`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a simple calculation using the viewport dimensions of the scrollpane and the coordinates/dimensions of your node?
It would be easierto help if you could post a simple testcase to experiment with.